# WinJs.Pivot: How to change the font for one word (or to bold it)

Tags: javascript, css, winjs, pivotitem

I am making an application for Windows Phone, using the Javascript Hub Template and I have a 2 possible scenarios:

1) I use the resource.resjson to name the headers of the pivot pages
2) I create the pivot pages dynamically at runtime

My problem is that one of the pages has to have 2 words and I was asked to make the second word to be bold

Like: my **house**

And I couldn´t find anyway to make this second word of the pivot item header to be bold.

Any ideas?

(here is a part of the code)

Resource.resjson:

```
"Section1": "my house"
```

Runtime:

```
var sectionHome = new WinJS.UI.PivotItem(loadBannerMovies(true), {header: "my house"});
            pivot.items.push(sectionHome);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting HTML directly in the resource string, e.g. "my <strong>house</strong>"? This typically works in other contexts, because such strings are usually just inserted in the overall resulting HTML for the control, though I haven't tried it in the Pivot control.

Comment: Yes... I did. I have tried using <b> but it does not allow the "<" anywhere...

Comment: I have also tried making 2 strings: var my = "my"; var house = "house"; to check whether I could format one of them.... but in Js, you can´t unless there´s an html object (it seems) ...

Comment: I have just tried using split() and writing the <b> between ' ', but it did not work either